# How to merge one branch into another while resolving conflicts

Tags: git, merge, branch, merge-conflict-resolution

I have 3 branches: `master`, `quick-fixes` and `big-feature`. Both `quick-fixes` and `big-feature` have changes in them relative to master, but now I want to merge `quick-fixes` into `big-feature`. I can do:

```
git fetch
git checkout big-feature
git merge quick-fixes
git commit -m "Merged quick-fixes into big-feature"
git push
```

and if there is no conflict, this works absolutely perfectly - all changes from `quick-fixes` are now in `big-feature`. However, if there is a conflict, I get a message: *CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in `file` Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.* So, I resolve the conflict in a text editor and save the file.

However, after that, **the current branch is `quick-fixes`, not `big-feature`**. Meaning, if I just commit and push like before, all the changes from `big-feature` will be in `quick-fixes`, which is very bad.

Is there a way to merge one branch into another, resolve the conflict between them, and then have the merge commit be only in the target branch, and not the source branch?

Answer (score 0):

Lol, I was using using `git reset --hard origin/big-feature` to make 100% sure that I was on the correct branch, but it **DOESN'T WORK** and it was printing I was on `quick-fixes` when I used `git branch`, you have to do `git checkout big-feature` instead.

Sad that the hard reset command doesn't actually hard reset your repository.